# How ro reduce the mysql query running time

Tags: mysql

This is my query running in one page of my site

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT b.CruisePortID,
    b.SailingDates,
    b.CruisePortID,
    b.ArriveTime,
    b.DepartTime,
    b.PortName,
    b.DayNumber
FROM
    cruise_itineraries a,
    cruise_itinerary_days b,
    cruise_ports c
WHERE
a.ID = b.CruiseItineraryID
AND a.CruisePortID = c.ID
AND a.ID = '352905'
AND b.CruisePortID != 0
GROUP BY b.DayNumber;
```

while running this query in phpmy admin its take 3.20 sec because of cruise_itineraries had more 300 000 records
I tried indexing also after indexing it show 2.92 sec. Is any possible to reduced query time less .10 sec. Its help my site performance

here  details

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cruise_itineraries` (
  `cl` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `Description` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `SailingPlanID` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `VendorID` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `VendorName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `ShipID` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `ShipName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Duration` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DestinationID` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `CruisePortID` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `TradeRestriction` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cruise_itinerary_days` (
  `cld` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CruiseItineraryID` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `SailingDates` datetime NOT NULL,
  `VendorID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `VendorName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `ShipID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ShipName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `SailingPlanID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PlanName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `DayNumber` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `PortName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `CruisePortID` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `ArriveTime` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `DepartTime` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cruise_ports` (
  `cp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ID` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Description` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `NearestAirportCode` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `UNCode` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `City` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `StateCode` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `CountryCode` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `PostalCode` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Phone` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Fax` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Directions` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `Content` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `HomePageURL` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Longitude` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Latitude` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `CarnivalID` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


    ALTER TABLE `cruise_itineraries`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`cl`),
  ADD KEY `ID_2` (`ID`);

    ALTER TABLE `cruise_itineraries`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`cl`),
  ADD KEY `ID_2` (`ID`);


ALTER TABLE `cruise_itinerary_days`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`cld`);

ALTER TABLE `cruise_ports`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`cp`);


ALTER TABLE `cruise_itineraries`
  MODIFY `cl` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `cruise_itinerary_days`
  MODIFY `cld` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `cruise_ports`
  MODIFY `cp` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

**EXPLAIN RESULT:**

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref   | rows    | Extra                                                  |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | ref  | ID_2          | ID_2 | 8       | const |       1 | Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL  |    3267 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL  | 2008191 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)     |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------+

+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+---------+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                      | key                                | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra                                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+---------+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | ref  | Idx_CruiseItineraryID_CruisePortID | Idx_CruiseItineraryID_CruisePortID | 9       | const |   12 | Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort       |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | ref  | ID_2                               | ID_2                               | 8       | const |    1 | Distinct                                                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | ALL  | NULL                               | NULL                               | NULL    | NULL  | 3267 | Using where; Distinct; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+---------+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: post all the related table structure. I mean create table code.

Comment: means you want data structure for these tables right?

Comment: Also state what indexes you have on the tables

Comment: create table statement example: `CREATE TABLE MyGuests (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50),
reg_date TIMESTAMP
)`

Comment: Hi Eric,
This is the index i added
 ALTER TABLE `cruise_itineraries`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`cl`),
  ADD KEY `ID_2` (`ID`);

Comment: Hi subrata, 
update details in my question

Comment: Please tell me the usage of these two fields : **cruise_itineraries.cl** AND **cruise_itineraries.ID**

Comment: `EXPLAIN
SELECT 
    DISTINCT b.CruisePortID,
    b.SailingDates,
    b.CruisePortID,
    b.ArriveTime,
    b.DepartTime,
    b.PortName,
    b.DayNumber
FROM
    cruise_itineraries a,
    cruise_itinerary_days b,
    cruise_ports c
WHERE
a.ID = b.CruiseItineraryID
AND a.CruisePortID = c.ID
AND a.ID = '352905'
AND b.CruisePortID != 0
GROUP BY b.DayNumber;` Run this query and share the result please.

Comment: cruise_itineraries.cl used as primary id and cruise_itineraries.ID  used for unique id

Comment: since cruise_itineraies.cl is primary key so it serves the purpose of uniqueness too!

Comment: yes but for our reference we use primary and unique

Comment: added that result also subrata.can you check it now?

Comment: as you can see the number of scanned rows from cruise_itinerary_days table is **huge**!!

Comment: Ya friend i already told that while asking help. Is there any way to reduce that query time. 

this is the part of query for particular page. i also most customized except this. any suggestion for optimize this records like indexing or some other

Comment: I am trying to point out the faults. some more time needed.

Comment: sure and thanks friend but please ASAP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I would like to state that try to avoid **IMPLICIT MySQL JOINS**.
Use **INNER JOINS** instead.

> I personally think the INNER JOIN is better, because it is more
>   readable. It shows better the relations between the table. You got
>   those relations in the join, and you do the filtering in the WHERE
>   clause. This separation makes the query more readable.

The faults I've found:

- The data type of **cruise_itineraries.ID** is **BIGINT** and the data type of **cruise_itinerary_days.CruiseItineraryID** is **varchar**. But you are matching them in a query. So it will run slow **no matter if you use index on cruise_itinerary_days.CruiseItineraryID** in **cruise_itinerary_days** table.

  Change the data type of cruise_itinerary_days.CruiseItineraryID  to BIGINT.

  `ALTER TABLE cruise_itinerary_days MODIFY CruiseItineraryID BIGINT;`
- Next you have to create a composite index on cruise_itinerary_days table based on your query.

  `ALTER TABLE cruise_itinerary_days ADD INDEX Idx_CruiseItineraryID_CruisePortID` (`CruiseItineraryID`, `CruisePortID`)`
- Now create an index in cruise_ports table on cruise_ports.ID field.

  ALTER TABLE `cruise_ports` ADD INDEX `Idx_cruise_ports_ID` (`ID`);

And finally the query is formulated using INNER JOINS since I've stated reasons above behind this choice:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT b.CruisePortID,
    b.SailingDates,
    b.CruisePortID,
    b.ArriveTime,
    b.DepartTime,
    b.PortName,
    b.DayNumber
FROM cruise_itineraries a
INNER JOIN cruise_itinerary_days b ON a.ID = b.CruiseItineraryID
INNER JOIN cruise_ports c ON a.CruisePortID = c.ID
WHERE a.ID = 352905
AND b.CruisePortID != 0
GROUP BY b.DayNumber;
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. i will implement and share the result with you

Comment: Please share the EXPLAIN result of this query.

Comment: Sounds great! !@vigneshrajkumar

Comment: Share the **EXPLAIN RESULT** please @vigneshrajkumar

Comment: `cruise_ports` needs `INDEX(ID)`, too.

Comment: I've modified my answer adding that particular index in `cruise_ports` table. Thank you @RickJames

Comment: Please practice marking answer as **Accepted** if it works for you. So that others find it useful. [**How to accept answer**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) @vigneshrajkumar